# Where does TinyUmbrella keep settings files on Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, jailbreak

I just did a clean install and don't want to restore from Time Machine, where does TinyUmbrella keep all the device names and settings? I have all my shsh files, but there is no device listed on TinyUmbrella, I want to back up shsh for my mom's iPhone (I had it on my device list and was able to back up without physically connecting it to my Mac) and she is across the Pacific ocean...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this in a while, but whenever I wanted to find out where a program kept files on my Mac, I would start up the utility CleanApp (meant for deinstalling apps), which could then show me exactly where all the program's files were. You could try this out (CleanApp has a free trial as far as I remember) and see if anything turns up.

Comment: TinyUmbrella is a java application, so CleanApp does not show any other file than the program itself.

Comment: Aha, ok, didn't know that, sorry.